# Get notified when RSS feed becomes dead

Tags: automation, rss

I would like to get a notification (in RSS or e-mail) when an RSS feed becomes dormant/dead.

There is a RSS feed I would like to monitor. As long there are changes, it's fine. I'm talking about this feed:

- https://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=feedcontributions&user=XxmarijnwBot&feedformat=atom
- https://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=feedcontributions&user=XxmarijnwBot&feedformat=rss

However when the feed didn't update for 24 hours there is something wrong. At that moment I would like to receive a notification.

Does anyone have an idea what app or script I could use for this? I would like to avoid subscribing to the full feed and marking it as read every day.